# Issue in splitting into list in python

Tags: python

This is my python code. In this code, the str1 field contains the output of the user command (w).
The last field(WHAT) can contain one or more spaces. 
I am trying to create a list from the output of the command (w).

Issue: In the 2nd row, FROM field does not contain any value due to that I am not getting the expected output. If it(FROM field) contains any value, then I am getting the expected output.

Code:

```
import re
lista, listb, list_final =[],[],[]
str1 = '''17:36:34 up 17 days,  1:48,  3 users,  load average: 6.33, 5.37, 5.46
USER     TTY      FROM             LOGIN@   IDLE   JCPU   PCPU WHAT
Arul     abc/0    10.XXX.XX.X1     14:41    2:31m  2.04s  1.97s ssh centos@ABC.DEF.H.I
Peter    abc/1                     17:36    1.00s  0.08s  0.02s w
Joe      abc/3    10.XXX.XX.X3     13:59    2:41m  4:38   0.08s /opt/ google  /  chrome/chrome'''

str1 = re.sub('  +', ' ', str1)
lista = str1.splitlines ()
lista = lista[2:]
listb=[re.split(" ", el, maxsplit=7) for el in lista]
print (listb)
```

The above code produce the result as below
Result:

```
[['Arul', 'abc/0', '10.XXX.XX.X1', '14:41', '2:31m', '2.04s', '1.97s', 'ssh centos@ABC.DEF.H.I'],
['Peter', 'abc/1', '17:36', '1.00s', '0.08s', '0.02s', 'w'],
['Joe', 'abc/3', '10.XXX.XX.X3', '13:59', '2:41m', '4:38', '0.08s', '/opt/ google / chrome/chrome']]
```

I am expecting the result as below. (if any of the field (FROM) contains a null value, the same should be populated in the list output.
Expected result:

```
[['Arul', 'abc/0', '10.XXX.XX.X1', '14:41', '2:31m', '2.04s', '1.97s', 'ssh centos@ABC.DEF.H.I'],
['Peter', 'abc/1', '            ', '17:36', '1.00s', '0.08s', '0.02s', 'w'],
['Joe', 'abc/3', '10.XXX.XX.X3', '13:59', '2:41m', '4:38', '0.08s', '/opt/ google / chrome/chrome']]
```

Comment: The header line with "USER", "TTY",... seems to give the width of the columns in the following rows. Just cut the rows using these widths, and remove trailing spaces in the entries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
lista, listb, list_final = [], [], []
str1 = '''17:36:34 up 17 days,  1:48,  3 users,  load average: 6.33, 5.37, 5.46
USER     TTY      FROM             LOGIN@   IDLE   JCPU   PCPU WHAT
Arul     abc/0    10.XXX.XX.X1     14:41    2:31m  2.04s  1.97s ssh centos@ABC.DEF.H.I
Peter    abc/1                     17:36    1.00s  0.08s  0.02s w
Joe      abc/3    10.XXX.XX.X3     13:59    2:41m  4:38   0.08s /opt/ google  /  chrome/chrome'''

lista = str1.splitlines()

first_row = lista[1]
indices = [first_row.index(x) for x in first_row.split()]
lista = lista[2:]
lines_splitted = []

#split according to first line
for line in lista:
    l = []
    for i in range(0, len(indices) - 1):
        l.append(line[indices[i]:indices[i + 1]])
    l.append(line[indices[-1]:])
    lines_splitted.append(l)

# adjust whitespaces
for index in range(0, 8):
    for line_splitted in lines_splitted:
        if line_splitted[index].isspace():
            lengths = [len(x[index].strip()) for x in lines_splitted]
            max_length = max(lengths)
            line_splitted[index] = line_splitted[index].strip() + ' ' * max_length

# remove others whitespaces
for index in range(0, 8):
    for line_splitted in lines_splitted:
        if not line_splitted[index].isspace():
            line_splitted[index] = line_splitted[index].strip()


print(*lines_splitted, sep='\n')
```

Comment: I used re.sub('  +', ' ', str1) code causing the issue. Is there a way in re.sub to convert more than one space into single space for the last field alone(WHAT field not for the other fields)?